# Zip array and mixed array in C#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have these two Lists

the first one is a `List<String> propsNames` that can look like these:

```
["Name", "Description", "HardwareID"]
```

and the other list is `List<Object> propValues` that can look like these:

```
["USB Input Device", "USB Input Device", ["USB\\VID_062A&PID_4102&REV_8113", "USB\VID_062A&PID_4102"]]
```

I want to zip the list and print it key- value(s) pair

```
var propNamesAndValues = propsNames.Zip(propValues, (pName, pValue) => new { propName = pName, propValue = pValue });   

 foreach (var item in propNamesAndValues)
 {
     sb.AppendLine(item.propName + ": " + item.propValue);                
 }
```

these will output me (on `sb.ToString();`)

```
    Name: USB Input Device
    Description: USB Input Device
    HardwareID: System.String[]
```

but I want

```
Name: USB Input Device
Description: USB Input Device
HardwareID: USB\\VID_062A&PID_4102&REV_8113, USB\VID_062A&PID_4102
```

how can i achieve these?

please note that the `propValues` may not contain sub-array and if it does it location may vary.

**Edit**: i cannot change and  `propValues` type because I'm getting the result through reflection and i cannot determine the output before run-time

Comment: Change the List<Object> to List<String>, they all look like strings.

Comment: One of your `Object` is actually an array. This is why the `item.propValue` is returning `System.String[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `string.Join`. When iterating through `propValues` check if item is a string. And if not you can cast it to IEnumerable

Try this code:

```
var propsNames = new List<string> {"Name", "Description", "HardwareID"};
var propValues = new List<object> {"USB Input Device", "USB Input Device", new List<object> {"USB\\VID_062A&PID_4102&REV_8113", "USB\\VID_062A&PID_4102" }};

var propsAndValues = propsNames.Zip(propValues, (name, value) => new {name, value});
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in propsAndValues)
{
    var value = item.value is string 
      ? item.value 
      : string.Join(", ", (IEnumerable<object>)item.value);
    sb.AppendLine(item.name + ": " + value);
}
```

Note that this code expect only 2 level nested array. If your `propValues` may looks like

> ["1", "2", ["3", ["4", "5"]], "6"]

then you need to parse it recursively

Comment: i was trying to do something like `((System.Collections.IEnumerable)item).Cast<object>()
                                .Select(x => x.ToString())
                                .ToArray();`

but i was getting `Cannot convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable`

do you know why?

Comment: @styx I think it is because you need to cast  `item.propValue` instead of `item`

Answer (score 2):

You need to check whether the propValue is a string[] first before using it, and if so then pull the items out of there. So something like this should work:

```
var propNamesAndValues = propsNames.Zip(propValues, (pName, pValue) => new { propName = pName, propValue = pValue });

var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in propNamesAndValues)
{
    var sb2 = new StringBuilder();
    if (item.propValue.GetType() == typeof(string[]))
    {              
        foreach (var listItem in item.propValue as string[])
        {
            sb2.Append(listItem + ", ");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        sb2.Append(item.propValue);
    }

    sb.AppendLine(item.propName + ": " + sb2.ToString());
}
```

Comment: i came to something similar myself, but @Aleks Andreev solution is more elegant

Comment: Performance note: you do not need second `StringBuilder`. Just add all text to first one